# MySql IN Clause Issue in SubQuery

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT users.id, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(languages.language) FROM languages WHERE languages.id IN (users.languages)) as languages FROM users
```

In my users.languages column, the value is 3,2,5

When I directly place that value, it returns English, German, French. But when I place users.languages in the IN Clause, it only returns English. Does anybody know what am I missing.

```
Languages table
id  language    lang_code
1   English     en
2   Dutch       nl
3   German      de
4   Spanish     fr
5   French      es

Users table
id languages
1  1,3,5
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store lists in a comma-separated string.  Here are several good reasons:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- Ids should have identified foreign key relationships, which you cannot do when you store integers as strings.
- SQL (in general) has poor support for strings.

The right way to store such a list is a junction table.  In your case, this would be `UserLanguages` with one row per use and one row per language.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really bad design decisions. MySQL offers `find_in_set()` to help with this situation:

```
SELECT u.id,
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(l.language)
       FROM languages l
       WHERE FIND_IN_SET(l.id, u.languages)
      ) as languages
FROM users u;
```

However, the proper query using a junction table would be:

```
SELECT u.id,
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(l.language)
       FROM UserLanguages ul JOIN
            languages l
            ON ul.LanguageId = l.id
       WHERE ul.UserId = u.id
      ) as languages
FROM users u;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I know storing comma separated values is not a good structure implementation, but I am still confused why IN clause did not work out, and when I was directly placing comma separated integers in my query it worked. Is it because the u.languages is a string of comma separated integers and not just a comma separated list of integers ?

Comment: @Deepanshu . . . I think you understand why it is not working.  A string is not the same as a list.

Comment: Great... I am glad I asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

It should be another `SELECT` query returning one column:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`languages`.`language`) FROM `languages`
  WHERE `languages`.`id` IN (
    SELECT `languages` FROM `users`
  )
) as `languages` FROM `users`
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but it did not work. I know the way you are talking about, but I have no idea why even my query is not working. Just check the db structure I updated in my question

Comment: @Deepanshu I guessed it, Can you please create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?